# How to replace certain symbol in array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, variables

Can you give me a hint what do I wrong trying to replace space symbol (' ') to ('-').

This is my code:

```js
function hypernateAndLowerCase(strings)
{
  let newArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) { 
    if (strings[i].indexOf(' ')){
       strings[i].replace(' ', '-');

    }

    newArray.push(strings[i].toLowerCase());
  }
  return newArray;
}

console.log(hypernateAndLowerCase(['HELLO WORLD', 'HELLO YOU']));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just doing `"strings[i].replace(' ', '-');"` won't do anything, you need to reassign the value of each `strings[i]`. So replace `strings[i].replace(' ', '-')` with `strings[i] = strings[i].replace(' ', '-');`

Answer (score 3):

`.replace` does not mutate the original string - strings are immutable, so you'd have to explicitly assign the result of using `replace` for it to work. But, `.map` is more appropriate here, since you want to transform one array into another:

```js
function hypernateAndLowerCase(strings) {
  return strings.map(string => string.replace(' ', '-').toLowerCase());
}

console.log(hypernateAndLowerCase(['HELLO WORLD', 'HELLO YOU']));
```

Note that passing a string to `.replace` will mean that, at most, only one occurrence will be replaced. If you want *all* occurrences to be replaced, use a global regular expression instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your function to following

```js
function hypernateAndLowerCase(strings) {
  return strings.map(v => v.replace(/ /g, "-").toLowerCase());
}

console.log(hypernateAndLowerCase(['HELLO WORLD', 'HELLO YOU']));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.map()` and `.replace()` methods. Use of `\s+`  in regular expression will allow you to replace one or more spaces with hyphen.

```js
let hypernateAndLowerCase = (data) => data.map(
    str => str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()
);

console.log(hypernateAndLowerCase(['HELLO WORLD', 'HELLO YOU', 'HELLO   WORLD']));
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created a Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/o0bq2rhg/

```
function hypernateAndLowerCase(strings) {
    let newArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        if (strings[i].indexOf(' ') > -1) {
            strings[i] = strings[i].replace(/ /g, '-');
        }

        newArray.push(strings[i].toLowerCase());
    }
    return newArray;
}

console.log(hypernateAndLowerCase(['HELLO WORLD', 'HELLO YOU']));
```

You have to store the outcome of the replaced function back into `strings[i]`. I've replaced the the function with a regex so you replace all spaces at once: `trings[i].replace(/ /g, '-');`. Replace only replaces the first occurrence.